# Is there a big difference between specialised wall smoothing pastes and joint filler/finsiher?

Tags: walls, finishing

I have been renovating some interior walls that were damaged through age and the process of removing wallpaper.  I didn't want to replaster, and I wanted a very thin covering, so I opted for a big-brand wall smoothing paste (or actually "Enduit de Lissage" in the local language). There are similar products from a few manufacturers.

The product wasn't as easy to employ as suggested (lots of sanding and touching-up is required) but the results look acceptable so far.

However, the product is expensive and I am now wondering whether there is a big difference between it and joint filler or joint finisher compound which seems a fraction of the price.

Is there any advantage to the specialist product?

Comment: Note: I decided to remove the name of the actual product I used, but if you search for "smooth damaged walls" you will see the kind of thing.

Comment: Probably not. There's no harm in sharing a product name in cases like this, where you're comparing _types_ of products. What specific claims does it make?

Comment: you should wet the wall before using joint compound on large areas. the fancy stuff might not need that step, making it quicker/easier for that task.

Comment: The product I used is from Pollycell. I bought it in Belgium, so the name is French "Enduit de Lissage" which just means "Smoothing covering" The UK equivalent is called "Smoothover". There are similar products from other manufactures such as Toupret. Smoothover is described here: https://www.polycell.co.uk/tutorials/polycell-smoothover-tutorial/.It looks and smells like a cross between paint and plaster. It claims to be self-leveling. I am not sure what that means really, but in my experience it still leaves a lot of "cats-faces" and irregularities and needs a lot of sanding after.